# Copy excel cell data till the nearest filled cell in column

Tags: excel, copy, cell

I am a total newbie to Excel, and there's a bit of problem I am facing.

I have an Excel sheet that I have to import into another program of mine. Please consider this format:

```
Heading1 |  Sub-heading1  |   Sub-Sub-heading1 
         |                |   Sub-Sub-heading2 
         |                |   Sub-Sub-heading3 
         |                |   Sub-Sub-heading4 
         |  Sub-heading2  |   Sub-Sub-heading1 
         |                |   Sub-Sub-heading2 
         |                |   Sub-Sub-heading3 
         |                |   Sub-Sub-heading4 
Heading2 |  Sub-heading1  |   Sub-Sub-heading1
and so on..
```

The problem is that for my import purpose I cannot leave any cells blanks. So, I wanted some  forumla through which `Heading1` can be copied to all the cells above `Heading2`, and similar for column2 and all the data appearing afterwards in all the rows.

This would be great help, since it would remove the roadblock for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very quick either manually (no code) or programmatically (simple code) using `SpecialCells` which has a xlBlanks collection

**1. Manually**

- Select the cells in your first two columns
- Press F5 ... Special ...Blanks
- In the formula bar type =A1 where A1 is the first cell above your new selection of blanks
- Hold the Ctrl key and press Enter to enter this formula in all the blank cells at once

This is written up well [here](http://contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html) including instructions as to how to convert these formulae to values

**2. VBA**

Three samples are provided [here](http://contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html#FillProg)

This modified version of the second code would work on columns A:B  (which appears to be your data layout)

```
Sub FillColBlanks_Offset()
'by Rick Rothstein  2009-10-24
'fill blank cells in column with value above
'http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html
'modified by brettdj
Dim Area As Range, LastRow As Long
On Error Resume Next
With Columns("A:B")
    LastRow = .Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
    For Each Area In .Resize(LastRow). _
        SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
        Area.Value = Area(1).Offset(-1).Value
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are approx. 500 `Headings`, and accordingly several `sub-headings` and `sub-subheadings`. Is there any way to detect he last filled cell and copy upto that point, to make it fast?

Comment: @Cipher. Both methods will do that as SpecialCells works within the actual UsedRange, ie if you work with Column A&B then only the used portion of the spreadsheet will be updated (Even if it didn't Rick's code finds the last used cell).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for this. Saved the day!